# C# Проблема с указателями при создании связного списка

Tags: c#, указатели

Добрый день!
Требуется создать связный список объектов структуры, в котором текущий элемент должен указывать на следующий, последний - на null. На C++ когда делал подобное - проблем не возникло. На C# первый элемент создается без проблем. Но второй создается с тем-же адресом! Как это исправить?

```
// Структура объектов очереди
struct QueueItem
{
    public int Value;
    public unsafe QueueItem* Next;

    public unsafe QueueItem(int value) : this()
    {
        Value = value;
        Next = null;
    }
}

class QueueWithMinStats
{
    private unsafe QueueItem* _first;
    private unsafe QueueItem* _last;
    public unsafe QueueWithMinStats()
    {
        _first = null;
        _last = null;
    }

    // Добавить в очередь значение
    public unsafe void Enqueue(int value)
    {
                  // Проблема тут!!!
        var newItem = new QueueItem(value);
        var newItemLink = &newItem;

        if (_first == null) // Если вводимый элемент - первый
            _first = newItemLink;
        else
            _last->Next = newItemLink;

        _last = newItemLink;        

    }
}
```

Comment: Если интересно, можете посмотреть как в .Net реализован [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Вы не должны использовать `unsafe`, если не понимаете, что это ключевое слово означает. И нативные указатели. Иначе вы сами себе создаёте проблему.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Применительно к структуре, оператор `new` не выделяет память, а лишь вызывает конструктор. Сама структура каждый раз создается на стеке в одном и том же месте - неудивительно что указатели одинаковы.

Для того, чтобы структура "перенеслась" в кучу - надо кастануть ее к типу object (эта операция называется упаковкой). Но у упакованной структуры получить адрес средствами языка - не так-то и просто...

Поэтому предлагаю вам сделать все по-другому.

Во-первых, замените структуру на класс (значимый тип на ссылочный).
Во-вторых, уберите указатели: для ссылочных типов они не нужны.

Вместе с другими, не столь критичными, исправлениями, получится как-то так:

```
class QueueWithMinStats
{
    class QueueItem // я перенес этот класс внутрь, потому что за пределами реализации очереди он никому не должен быть интересен
    {
        public int Value;
        public QueueItem Next;

        public QueueItem(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
            // Next инициализаровать не надо - поля классов инициализируются значениями по умолчанию автоматически
        }
    }

    private QueueItem _first;
    private QueueItem _last;

    // Конструктор пока не нужен

    public void Enqueue(int value)
    {
        // Проблемы больше нет!!!
        var newItem = new QueueItem(value);
        // Переменная newItemLink больше не нужна - потому что QueueItem - это ссылочный тип

        if (_first == null) // Если вводимый элемент - первый
            _first = newItem;
        else
            _last.Next = newItem;

        _last = newItem;        
    }
}
```